# PHP list directory files (not folders) not displaying files with > 3 character filetype e.g docx

Tags: php, directory

Beginner at php here. I hope you guys can help, here is the code I'm using:

```
$path = 'K:\_Intranet\General Documents';
$dir = opendir($path);

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !==   false) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
    {
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) ==".")
        {
            echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

Basically how do I get this to also display files with a 4 character file type e.g docx or xlsx?

I've tried using this but it still doesn't seem to work:

```
elseif (substr($file, -4) ==".")
            {
                echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
            }
```

Help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Php has functions is_file($filename) and is_dir($filename) which will return true if the named path is of the right type. Not putting this as answer as it is a proposal for a slightly different solution.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for commenting! Alec has demonstrated below the use of is_file yet I cannot seem to get it to work, can you check it please?

Comment: Hi there, it is as Alec suggests in his comment below.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for you; as the comment by Danny says, you can simply check to see if the specified path resolves to a file (as opposed to a directory).

```
$path = 'K:\_Intranet\General Documents';
$dir = opendir($path);

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !==   false) 
{
    if (is_file($file))
    {
        echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a></li>";
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

This means you don't specifically need to recognise that it has an extension of such length (which would fail if you were looking at more extensive file types, such as .vcproj files or .htaccess). An additional problem with user-defined string checking would be if there were multiple compound extensions (such as MyGame.vcxproj.filters) or no extension at all (such as README files). In this case (as with a lot of I/O functionality), it is best left to the language itself; they have much more extensive detection patterns, and are generally more portable than a custom implementation

Comment: Thanks for posting! I see what you mean with your reply, I've tried your code yet it returns nothing. I've even tried is_dir, this does display a "." which opens the directory and ".." which opens the next level up.

Comment: What might be happening is that `readdir($dir)` is returning a relative filename, and you are in another directory (ie, K:\_Intranet) and so you would be looking for K:\_Intranet\README and not K:\_Intranet\General Documents\README. Try making $file absolute, by doing something like `is_file($path . "\" . $file)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're testing (unless you're excluding files with no extension or files with extensions less than three or more than four characters in length) if you "also display files with a 4 character file type " but if you want to test for either 3 or 4 characters you could change this -

```
if (substr($file, -4, -3) ==".")
```

to something like this

```
if ((substr($file, -4) ==".") || (substr($file, -5) =="."))
```

The first condition matches the "." on files with 3 letter extensions. The second, files with 4 letter extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = 'K:\_Intranet\General Documents';
$dir = opendir($path);

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !==   false) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
    {
        $format=end(explode(".", $file));
        if ($format=="docx" || $format=="xlsx")
        {
            echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying.
Jay Blanchard, big thanks to you.

```
$path = 'K:\_Intranet\General Documents';
$dir = opendir($path);

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !==   false) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
    {
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) ==".")
        {
            echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
        }
        elseif (substr($file, -5, -4) ==".")
        {
            echo "<li> <a target='_blank' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

This works like a charm it now lists all 3/4 extension filetypes!

I've also done the code to display just folders(this only works if you have just 3/4 extension filetypes):

```
$path = 'K:\_Intranet\General Documents';
$dh = opendir($path);

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) 
{
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
    {
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) ==".")
        {
            echo "";
        }
        elseif (substr($file, -5, -4) ==".")
        {
            echo "";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<img src='pictures/folder.png'></a> <a target='_top' href='$path/$file'>$file</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
closedir($dh);
```

If you have files with more or less extension filetypes then it's like what Alec said, you would need to specify each one.
So if for example you had a file with .db file type and you didn't want to list it you would need to add another:

```
elseif (substr($file, -3, -2) ==".")
        {
            echo "";
        }
```

It may be the long way around it but I kinda like it this way as you have more control of what is to be displayed.